# Connecting to MySQL through Excel by running a Macro

Tags: vba, excel

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO [ODBC;DSN=DSNName;].NameOfMySQLTable (IndexCode,LastTradePrice) VALUES"

strSQL = strSQL & "Select F1,G1 As NameOfMySQLField FROM [Excel 8.0;DATABASE=" & strFile & ";HDR=NO;IMEX=1].[Sheet1$];"
```

This is the query I write in MS Excel's macro. I have a database on server where I want this values to get inserted.

What is to be written in place of `[ODBC;DSN=DSNName;].NameOfMySQLTable` and in place of `NameOfMySQLField`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't connect to 2 databases (MySQL+Excel) in a single statement...

Comment: Do you know how to connect to a database from Excel using ADO ?

Comment: Nope. Can you give more information on how to do that?

Comment: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,100302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find something here useful:

http://www.heritage-tech.net/908/inserting-data-into-mysql-from-excel-using-vba/

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't find the DSNName. Can you tell what needs to be written in place of DSNName? Because in my query, I suppose it is a placeholder.